# WordPress: Re-direct unique logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

So here's what I'm trying to do in WordPress / PHP;

1. Redirect a user from: `https://example.com/members/username/`
2. To this address: `https://example.com/members/username/profile/edit/group/1/`

This would just be a normal re-direct but 'username' will be unique each time.

I've tried storing the user as a variable:

```php
$username = wp_get_current_user();
```

Then replacing username in the URL with `$username` to make it:

`https://example.com/members/$username/profile/edit/group/1/`

This results in a PHP error as I need to convert the object to a string.

I've tried creating a class to convert an object to a string but it didn't work.

Please help!

Comment: Telling us that you wrote some code that didn't work is entirely useless. Post the code, and explain what went wrong. And post a definition of the object you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation of Wordpres, says that the `wp_get_current_user()` function returns an instance of `WP_User` class.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/

Now, this class has a Magic Method to access the user's data, in particular to access the username you could try to do the following:

```
$currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

$currentUsername = $currentUser->user_login;
```

So at the end you will probably end up with a thing like this:

```
$currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

$currentUsername = $currentUser->user_login;

$url = sprintf("https://example.com/members/%s/profile/edit/group/1/", $username);

wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

**Update**

after searching on the official documentation, i found that you can  return the url in the apply_filter callback instead of call directly the wp_redirect function like this:

```
function custom_login_redirect() { 
   $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

   $currentUsername = $currentUser->user_login;

   $url = sprintf("https://example.com/members/%s/profile/edit/group/1/", $username);

  return $url
}
```

after that you need to register this "event" using the `add_filter` function.

like this:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect');
```

here the link of the official doumentation of wordpress, at the bottom of the page there are some example of usage of this filter provided by the comunity.

link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/

About where to tput the code:
if ypou put the code in template, this will be overvritten after next updat of your theme, so i saccomand to use and extension that allows you to insert and execute custom codes in wordpress like `Code Snippets`.
I havent tested the code snippet extension but it should be easy to setup, by the way you could use one of the others similar extensions

Comment: Thanks JDarwind, I really appreciate your help. 

I've tried adding the above code to the top and then bottom of the functions.php file but get the following error ''Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted."

Is there another file you'd recommend to add the code?

Comment: i think you need to write a function like this in order to get the user redirected after login:
`
function custom_login_redirect() {

//your code gose here

}
`
after this you need to bind the login event with the new created  function using the `add_filter` function`
To do so you need to call the add_filter function this way `add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect');`.
To insert the code you could (i think it's a good choice) use a plugin that let you insert custom code in your website.

Comment: **Important** before make changes to uor wordpress site, it's a good idea to make a complete bacub of files and of the DB in order to restore it in case of any problem

Comment: Here a readble version of the function :
` function custom_login_redirect() { //your code gose here } `

Comment: Hi JDarwind, thanks for the updates, I'm still working on this and think I may have found an easier solution. Instead of trying to redirect I just need to change; 

<a href="<?php bp_loggedin_user_link() ?>" 

to <a href="<?php bp_loggedin_user_link() + '/profile/edit/group/1/'; ?>". 

Do you know how to add this bit to the shortcode properly "+'/profile/edit/group/1/';" ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorted! > a href="<?php bp_loggedin_user_link() ?>profile/edit/group/1/"

Comment: Great! you could also do something like this: `a href="<?php sprintf("%sprofile/edit/group/1/", bp_loggedin_user_link());?>"`